# How to restrict read access to directory for specific user in centos?

Tags: centos, files, permissions, chmod, setfacl

So here is the deal, I create directory `/home/accounting`, I have users `donna` and `mike` and I want to restrict read privileges for them to this directory.

After going to Google I was able to find how to change permissions by `chmod` for my user and my group, but I was not really able to find how I can specify user in that command.

Then I found the `setfacl` command, but not sure if it enables permission or not, for example these two commands::

```
setfacl -R -m u:donna:r /home/accounting
setfacl -R -m u:mike:r /home/accounting
```

Is this correct? Or there is another way of revoking read access?

Comment: What you're trying to do is called "chroot" or "jail", so you can look up details on how those work. You don't mention how they are accessing the files, EG: samba, nfs, shell, ftp, so it's hard to give you specific suggestions.

Comment: The golden rule is: "Try to understand what you are doing". That means: Read the manual page for `setfacl`, `chmod` and `getfacl` before using those commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to decline the read permissions to the directory `/home/accounting` you could use

```
chmod o-r /home/accounting
```

Where `o` stands for `others`, `-` is basically removing or decling and `r` is read permission.